# Escondendo div pelo jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código no jQuery:

```
$('#btnFiltros').click(function () {
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'collapse');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'none');
    }
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'collapse') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Preciso esconder a div se o atributo `visibility` for igual a `visible` e exibir a `div` caso o atributo seja igual a `collapse`.
O problema é que ele entra no primeiro `if` faz o que eu quero e em seguida entra no segundo `if` escondendo a div novamente. Como faço para não entrar no segundo `if` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em resumo, você está usando dois `if()` e sem nenhum retorno. Dessa forma, ele irá entrar nos dois. Uma "alternativa" (gambiarra em minha opinião) seria colocar um retorno no `if()`. Seria algo como isso:

```
$('#btnFiltros').click(function () {
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'collapse');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'none');
        return;
    }
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'collapse') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Porém, existe mais duas opções melhores.

A primeira é utilizar somente o `if()` e `else()`, desta forma:

```
$('#btnFiltros').click(function () {
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'collapse');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else{
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Dessa forma ele entrará no primeiro ou no segundo, mas nunca nos dois.

Uma segunda opção seria utilizar o `else if()`. Dessa forma pode ter mais de uma condição, mas só "entrará" na primeira condição aceita.

Ficaria desta forma:

```
$('#btnFiltros').click(function () {
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'collapse');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'collapse') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Você ainda pode adicionar mais `else if` ou um `else()` no final.

Lembrando, que você também pode utilizar um `switch()`, dependendo do caso.

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar um retorno dentro do primero `IF`, para que não prossiga a execução:

```
$('#btnFiltros').click(function () {
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'collapse');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'none');
        return true;
    }
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'collapse') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `Hide/Show` do `jquery` para esconder a sua DIV. 
Link de tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Exemplo do tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

Nota-se: Quando entra no primeiro `if` você faz com que a propriedade `visibility` receba "collapse", consequentemente no `if` seguinte ele é verdadeiro e entra também!

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a melhor alternativa seja mesmo uma das que o Randrade mencionou

```
$('#btnFiltros').click(function () {
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'collapse');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'collapse') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

ou

```
   $('#btnFiltros').click(function () {
    if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'collapse');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else{
        $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

No entanto, caso queira usar apenas uma variável, pode ser feito assim :

```
var visivel = true;
 $('#btnFiltros').click(function () {
        if (visivel  === true) {
            $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'collapse');
            $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'none');
            visivel = false;
        }else if (visivel   === false) {
            $('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#divFiltros').css('display', 'block');
            visivel = true;
        }
    });
```

Essa opção é válida para evitar a comparação feita pelo .css. 
Veja o que o artigo do Tableless diz.

> *Olhando o código-fonte do jQuery, o método .css() possui aproximadamente 20 linhas (sem contar outros métodos chamados). A atribuição acima poderia ser executada da seguinte forma, com uma única linha:*
>   [jQuery: dicas de otimização e performance](http://tableless.com.br/jquery-dicas-de-otimizacao-e-performance/)

Resumindo, com o uso da variável, você fará apenas uma comparação simples de uma variável.

Espero ter ajudado.